# Elastic search not considering as string field by default and not giving proper matching results

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-query

I am querying ElasticSearch by using the following query and it is giving me results as per the query along with some other irrelevant data.

```
GET items/_search
{
  "query" :{
      "match": {"code": "*7000-8002-W*"}
  }
}
```

But if I query like this, I am getting the proper results:

```
GET items/_search
{
  "query" :{
      "match": {"code": "*S6617523*"}
  }
}
```

Why is the first query returns some other irrelevant data?

Comment: can you post what are you getting and what do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is due to the way ES analyzes the string. In this case you need to apply `wildcard` query on raw field of `code` like

```
{ 
"query": { 
 "wildcard": { 
  "code.keyword": { 
  "value": "*7000-6000*" 
    } 
   } 
  } 
 }
```

Java API orresponding to this will be

`QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("code.keyword","*7000-6000*");`

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Thankyou soo much !!

Comment: Happy To help!!